# Android how to display/load server text file through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i have text files,stored on server ,and want them to be loaded on respective android apps through intents(for e.g adobe reader for pdf, Microsoft office for doc files..etc)
how can i achieve the same,because i can load text files from memory card but online files from server are not loaded through intents in android

Comment: Did you have all data in form of string .. and U need to put it on your app for using all sort of thing ex: pdf and doc etc. ???

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this link you can upload or download text files from sever into your memory card and then load from memory card.

http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/intent.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch data from server in your app. You can use REST/SOAP web services to achieve this. When you will get data in your app in string or any other format you can use appropriate intent to access or open that data.